# Understanding Bubble SORT

Tags: c, while-loop, bubble-sort

```
didswaps = 1;
while(didswaps){
    didswaps = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        if(A[i]>A[i+1]) {
            int_swap(&A[i], &A[i+1]);
            didswaps = 1;
        }
    }    
}
```

What is the point of having didswaps in there ?

Comment: It will make the code efficient by breaking out early when the array becomes sorted either at the start or during the middle of sorting. So the loop doesn't have to run N*N times.

Answer (score 0):

It detects the work is not done yet: once some scan did not make any swap, `didswaps == 0` causes the loop to terminate, thus saving time of unnecessary scans.

Answer (score 0):

If `didswaps` remains `0` it means that every two neighbor elements are correctly sorted, so it ends the sorting algorithm faster(earlier)

Answer (score 0):

You assign 1 to `didswaps` each time you're swaping 2 elements.

When at the end of your loop you got `didswaps > 0` you had modifications and the list isn't sorted.

But if `didswaps == 0` Your list is sorted ;)

Comment: He does not '+1', he does '=1'.

Comment: @CiaPan Right ! Sorry. Still, it remains the same for the algo

Answer (score 0):

BubleSort iterates through the list until no swaps are needed, which indicates that the list is sorted.

`didswaps` indicates if a swap happened ( `didswaps` = 1). If no swap happened, then the list is sorted and therefore the while loop should be interrupted (`didswaps` = 0 ). The `didswaps` is used as boolean value, which can assume only the value 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The bubble sort algorithm can be easily optimized by observing that the `n`-th pass finds the `n`-th largest element and puts it into its final place. So, the inner loop can avoid looking at the last `n-1` items when running for the `n`-th time.

> If there is no swapping in a particular pass, it means the array has become sorted, so we should not perform the further passes. For this we can have a flag variable which is set to true before each pass and is made false when a swapping is performed.

The `didswaps` exactly does this optimization by excluding unnecessary passes.